# NoMethodError in Shippers#create after render controller_new_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My issue is I am checking the validation of a form_for with a nested fields_for inside of it to access the Address table where the user enters in basic information. If any information is incorrect rendering back to the page does not load. The error I am receiving is...

**NoMethodError in Shippers#create**

`undefined method 'addcheck' for #<Address:0x9fb9664>`

I feel this is because the checkbox is not a variable in the address table like the rest of the a.variables in the fields_for are. It is used to simply add the address to a Contacts table if it is checked.
I will add - - - to indicate where the errors were

The **view** for Shippers.new.html where the error occurred is

```
<%= fields_for :address do |a| %>
<div class="row"> 

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <label>Street Address <p class="help-block" style= "display:inline;" >  You can drag the marker to property position</p></label>
    <div>   
    <span id="latitude" class="label label-default"></span> <span id="longitude" class="label label-default"></span>
    </div>  


    <%=  a.text_field :street_address, :class=> "form-control", :id=> "address", :placeholder=> "Enter Starting Location", :autocomplete=> "on" %> 

</div>   
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Add Contact?</label>
-----------------------------------------------------
        <div class="checkbox custom-checkbox">
            <label><%= a.check_box :addcheck %>
            <span class="fa fa-check"></span></label>
        </div>         
------------------------------------------------------
    </div>
</div>
```

I am validating all information in the **model** by...

```
class CurrentPackage < ActiveRecord::Base

self.primary_key = :shipment_id
belongs_to      :address, foreign_key: "address_start"

validates :title, :presence => true
validates :total_cost, :presence => true
validates :weight, :presence => true
validates :dimensions, :presence => true
validates :user_id, :presence => true
```

The create action in my Shippers **controller** is...

```
def create

    @address = Address.where({street_address: params[:address][:street_address], city: params[:address][:city], state: params[:address][:state], zip_code: params[:address][:zip_code]}).first
    @shippers = CurrentPackage.new( user_params )
    @shippers.user_id = current_user
    @shippers.time_created = Time.now

    @address2 = Address.where({street_address: params[:address][:street_address2], city: params[:address][:city2], state: params[:address][:state2], zip_code: params[:address][:zip_code2]}).first


    if (!!@address) == false
        @address = Address.new(street_address: params[:address][:street_address], city: params[:address][:city], state: params[:address][:state], zip_code: params[:address][:zip_code])
        @address.save!
    end

    if (!!@address2) == false
        @address2 = Address.new(street_address: params[:address][:street_address2], city: params[:address][:city2], state: params[:address][:state2], zip_code: params[:address][:zip_code2])
        @address2.save!
    end

    @temp = @address.address_id 
    @shippers.address_start = @temp     

    @temp2 = @address2.address_id   
    @shippers.address_end = @temp2      

    #@shippers.save!      #replacing
    ------------------------------------------------------
    if @shippers.save
        #redirect_to @shippers
        redirect_to shippers_index_path

    else
        render shippers_new_path         #addcheck fails
        #render @shippers
        #redirect_to shippers_new_path   #works but loses data      
        #render 'new'                    #addcheck fails

    end
    --------------------------------------------------
    if (params[:address][:addcheck] == "1")

        if (!!Contact.where({user_id: current_user, contact: @temp}).first) == false
            hmm = Contact.new(user_id: current_user,contact: @temp)
            hmm.save!
        end
    end
    if (params[:address][:addcheck2] == "1")
        if (!!Contact.where({user_id: current_user, contact: @temp2}).first) == false
            hmm2 = Contact.new(user_id: current_user, contact: @temp2)
            hmm2.save!
        end
    end 

end
```

My **routes.rb** files looks like

```
get "shippers/isdriver"
get "shippers/index"
get "shippers/show"
get "shippers/update"
post "shippers/create"
get "shippers/new"
get "shippers/destroy"

devise_for :users
get "home/index"

resources :addcheck
```

I added the resources :addcheck because I saw another stackoverflow post said it worked for them, but not for me.

Just to reiterate, this only happens if the form is incorrect, goes into the else condition for the if @shippers.save, then it tries to load the new page again and breaks.

Any help would be INCREDIBLY appreciated :D

***** Additional Information *******
I took out the addcheck rails line, and ran again, but broke on the next field of :street_address2  for the same reason, because it is not actually a variable in any model, just a place holder.

Comment: This is one of the scenarios for which `strong parameters` have been introduced to ActionController. You should consider checking them out and maybe also using them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do you think this could explain though why it loads from a link, but upon rerendering from invalid data it crashes? I do have strong params for the "CurrentPackage.new( user_params )" but I can do the same for Address. If you think this explains its odd behavior, I can give it a shot.

Comment: It fails because `adcheck` is still associated to address. If you want to permanently solve this, maybe you should  make `adcheck` fall out of the `address` hash. Hence, in your view, instead of `<%= a.check_box`, probably better to use `<%= check_box_tag`, (see reply by @clark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than associating the check with the address model `<%= a.check_box :addcheck %>` I think you should make them independent `<%= check_box_tag(:addcheck) %>`

Comment: Yes! This was the correct approach! Thank you clark and Ruby Racer, you two are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the attribute before passing it to the model

```
if(params[:address].delete(:addcheck) == "1")
....
end
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly!
I added the line "if (params[:address].delete(:addcheck) == "1")" to see if this would address the issue, but it did not seem to change anything. I am never passing addcheck to the model, since its not part of the address table or any table, it is just part of a check if the user wants to add someone as a contact.

Comment: You must remove the attribute prior to doing the save

Comment: Im not entirely sure still howto correct this.
Could you possibly explain any reason why it works the first time, but only crashes after rerendering?

Comment: Robert, the attribute addcheck is not a real attribute but you are passing it in the model's create method when you call @shippers.save.  ActiveRecord is raising an error as it doesn't understand this attribute that you passed in so you must take measures to remove it from the params hash